# My simple Express Server won't serve static JS files

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express

My express (3.X) server looks like:

```
express = require "express"
app     = express()



app.configure ->
  app.use express.static(__dirname + '/public')
  app.use app.router


console.log __dirname + '/public'
app.get "*", (req, res) ->
  res.sendfile "index.html"


app.listen 1234
console.log "Server listening on port 1234"
```

I'm using it for an AngularJS project, so if anything is in the `/public` folder, I want it served directly. My `/public` folder has a `scripts` and `templates` folder in it.

However, when I go to `http://localhost:1234/public/scripts/app.js`, I get the contents of `index.html`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, `/public` is your webroot. You need to change your reference to `http://localhost:1234/scripts/app.js`.